# python3/contextlib: Converting @contextlib.contextmanager to acquire/release?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, decorator, contextmanager

I'm using some 3rd-party code which enables locking via routines that are decorated with `@contextlib.contextmanager`. I'm also using large python3 code base in which we can plug in different locking software, as long as I am able to implement `acquire` and `release` methods.

I'm trying to use the 3rd-party code (without knowing how it's written) within this software structure.

To clarify what I'm looking for, suppose that one of the 3rd-party lock routines is written as a standard `@contextlib.contextmanager` generator, like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def lock(arg0, arg1):
    try:
        # This section of code corresponds to `acquire`.
        # Acquire a lock called 'lock', and then ...
        yield lock
    finally:
        # This section of code coresponds to `release`.
        # Do cleanup.
```

It would normally be used like this ...

```
with third.party.lock(arg0, arg1):
    # Do stuff in this critical section
```

But as I mentioned above, I want to write a class that has an `acquire` method and a `release` method which make use of `third.party.lock`, and I'd like to do it via the existing `third.party.lock` module, without rewriting it.

In other words, I want to write a class which looks like this ...

```
class LockWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # initialization

    def acquire(self):
        # Use third.party.lock to obtain a lock.
        # ??? ??? ???

    def release(self):
        # I don't know what to do here. There is no yield
        # in the `finally` section of a normal
        # @contextlib.contextmanager decorated method/
        # ??? ??? ???
```

As I stated in the comments of my sample code, I don't see how to make `acquire` and `release` do anything meaningful.

It looks like I would have to steal code from the original `third.party.lock` module in order to accomplish this, but I'm hoping that I'm overlooking a way to do this without having to know anything about this 3rd-party code.

Am I out of luck?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. My answer is based on some of the code here: https://gist.github.com/icio/c0d3f7efd415071f725b

The key is this `enter_context` helper function, which digs into the structure of the context manager. It's similar to a function by the same name at that site ...

```
def enter_context(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def _acquire():
        with func(*args, **kwargs) as f:
            yield f
    acquire_gen = _acquire()
    def release_func():
        try:
            next(acquire_gen)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
    return acquire_gen, release_func
```

The following class implements `acquire` and `release` for any contextmanager function which is passed to the constructor. I encapsulate `enter_context` within this class ...

```
class ContextWrapper(object):
    @staticmethod
    def enter_context(func, *args, **kwargs):
        def _acquire():
            with func(*args, **kwargs) as f:
                yield f
        acquire_gen = _acquire()
        def release_func():
            try:
                next(acquire_gen)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        return acquire_gen, release_func
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self._acq, self._rel = self.__class__.enter_context(func, *args, **kwargs)
    def acquire(self):
        next(self._acq)
        return True
    def release(self):
        self._rel()
    # Traditional Dijkstra names.
    P = acquire
    V = release
```

Then, I can create my wrapper around `third.party.lock` as follows ...

```
mylocker = ContextWrapper(third.party.lock, arg0, arg1)
```

... and I can call `acquire` and `release` as follows ...

```
mylocker.acquire()
# or mylocker.P()
mylocker.release()
# or mylocker.V()
```

Here's another example of how to use this class ...

```
class ThirdPartyLockClass(ContextWrapper):
    def __init__(self, arg0, arg1):
        # do any initialization
        super().__init__(third.party.lock, arg0, arg1)
    # Implementing the following methods is optional.
    # This is only needed if this class intends to do more
    # than the wrapped class during `acquire` or `release`,
    # such as logging, etc.
    def acquire(self):
        # do whatever
        rc = super().acquire()
        # maybe to other stuff
        return rc
    def release(self):
        # do whatever
        super().release()
        # maybe do other stuff
    P = acquire
    V = release

mylocker = ThirdPartyLockClass(arg0, arg1)
mylocker.acquire()
# or mylocker.P()
mylocker.release()
# or mylocker.V()
```

... or I can even do the following in the simple case where no extra functionality is added to the third party lock class ...

```
class GenericLocker(ContextWrapper):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(func, *args, **kwargs)

mylocker = GenericLocker(third.party.lock, arg0, arg1)
mylocker.acquire()
# or mylocker.P()
mylocker.release()
# or mylocker.V()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the contextlib wrapper's `__enter__` and `__exit__` explicitly?

```
import contextlib

# Something to wrap
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Opening Test')
    def use(self):
        print('Using Test')
    def close(self):
        print('Closing Test')

# Wrap in the standard contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def test():
    try:
        t = Test()
        yield t
    finally:
        t.close()

# Does it work?  yes...
with test() as t:
    t.use()

# Implementing acquire/release...
class TestWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def acquire(self):
        self.t = test()
        return self.t.__enter__()
    def release(self):
        self.t.__exit__(None,None,None)

# Also works...
tw = TestWrapper()
t = tw.acquire()
t.use()
tw.release()
```

Output:

```
Opening Test
Using Test
Closing Test
Opening Test
Using Test
Closing Test
```